# Multiple RewriteRules for a single URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use multiple `RewriteRules` in `.htaccess` to modify a single URL, but only the last rule gets applied.

Example INPUT (link loaded by a browser):

```
http://example.com/aaa/foo/bar
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)foo/(.*)$ $1nofoo/$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)bar(.*)$ $1nobar$2
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT (what Apache should actually look at):

```
http://example.com/aaa/nofoo/nobar
```

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```
http://example.com/aaa/foo/nobar/
```

As you can see, only the last rule was applied. Is there any way to make it work the way I want? All suggestions are welcome.

PS. I want to avoid creating a static, ugly rule like

```
^(.*)foo/bar(.*) $1nofoo/nobar$2
```

I need all the modifications to work independently of each other.

**UPDATE**

So here is exactly what I am trying to achieve. I have some links to a backend server:

```
http://myserver.com/api/user/$userid/car/$carid/getSpeedRecordDetails
http://myserver.com/api/user/$userid/getUserDetails
http://myserver.com/api/car/$carid/getCarDetails
```

Where $userid and $carid are some unique 12-char-long strings.

And I want to transform them to these:

```
http://myserver.com/api/getSpeedRecordDetails.php?userid=$userid&carid=$carid
http://myserver.com/api/getUserDetails.php?userid=$userid
http://myserver.com/api/getCarDetails.php?carid=$carid
```

And I want to achieve it using the least RewriteRules possible (I am looking for a dynamic solution).

**UPDATE #2**

I love the SO community! Your patience and willingness to help is truly amazing :)

So the very reason why I am interested in modifying the URL using multiple RewriteRules is because I expect that my backend might soon need to implement hundreds (if not thousands) of user-friendly URLs, and mapping all of them individually would be a waste of time and money. Therefore, I want to take advantage of the fact that all the user-friendly URLs consist of repetitive chunks that can be easily translated. The calls below represent the general three types of the user-friendly URLs I need to manage. The only difference within each type is $userid, $carid, and XXXX_of_a_thousand_functions.

```
http://myserver.com/backend-api/user/$userid/car/$carid/first_of_a_thousand_functions.do
http://myserver.com/backend-api/user/$userid/second_of_a_thousand_functions.do
http://myserver.com/backend-api/car/$carid/sixteenth_of_a_thousand_functions.do
```

All of these calls (and remember, there will be hundreds, or even thousands of them) need to be translated into these:

```
http://myserver.com/backend-api/first_of_a_thousand_functions.php?USER_ID=$userid&CAR_ID=$carid
http://myserver.com/backend-api/second_of_a_thousand_functions.php?USER_ID=$userid
http://myserver.com/backend-api/sixteenth_of_a_thousand_functions.php?CAR_ID=$carid
```

Seeing that there is a simple pattern governing the translation (I hope it is also visible to you), I thought I could create some simple rules for translating different 'chunks' of the user-friendly URL into the internal URL. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)user/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(.*)$ $1$3&USER_ID=$2
```

Would be responsible for translating the piece `user/HSGRE8563LOS` into `&USER_ID=HSGRE8563LOS`

And because some calls have more than one 'chunk' to process, I need to be able to use multiple RewriteRules on a single URL, which I hope somewhat correlates with the title of the question :)

**UPDATE #3 - a future reference**

So there are a couple of things I believe need to be said regarding this question.

Apparently `.htaccess` **DOES** by default apply all the rules that the conditions of are met. However, some CGI/Fast-CGI installations ruin it, resulting in the kind of behaviour depicted in the first example.

Also, one thing I have NEVER seen mentioned anywhere is that Apache applies the `RewriteRules` not in the order in which they are listed in `.htaccess`, but it starts 'scanning' the URL from its beginning, and as soons as the conditions for ANY of the rules are met, the URL gets modified accordingly.

Comment: Your "example" would create a rewrite loop, can you make a more "real world" example? "OUTPU" - Are you suggesting this is an _external redirect_ or an _internal rewrite_ (as per your example)?

Comment: @w3dk Please take a look at my updated post

Comment: Your "update" is a completely different question?

Comment: Do you know how to solve either of them? :)

Comment: Just to clarify, regarding **update#2**, is "XXXX_of_a_thousand_functions" literally _some string_ (XXXX) followed by the literal string "_of_a thousand_functions", or you actually have thousands of functions?

Comment: @w3dk No, this is not literal. In reality the functions are called like getHistory, getDetails, getStatus etc, I just wanted to make it clear that there are many of them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After **UPDATE#1**... to *internally rewrite* from the stated friendly URLs using mod_rewrite. Try the following directives in the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# http://myserver.com/api/user/$userid/car/$carid/getSpeedRecordDetails
RewriteRule ^api/user/(\w{12})/car/(\w{12})/(getSpeedRecordDetails)$ /api/$3.php?userid=$1&carid=$2 [L]

# http://myserver.com/api/user/$userid/getUserDetails
RewriteRule ^api/user/(\w{12})/(getUserDetails)$ /api/$2.php?userid=$1 [L]

# http://myserver.com/api/car/$carid/getCarDetails
RewriteRule ^api/car/(\w{12})/(getCarDetails)$ /api/$2.php?carid=$1 [L]
```

`\w{12}` matches a 12 char long string of letters (upper/lower), numbers and underscore. However, this should be made as restrictive as possible. eg. if a valid id is only numeric then `\d{12}` would be preferable.

**UPDATE#2** The process is almost the same as above....

```
RewriteBase /backend-api

# http://myserver.com/backend-api/user/$userid/car/$carid/<any>.do
RewriteRule ^backend-api/user/(\w{12})/car/(\w{12})/(\w+)\.do$ $3.php?USER_ID=$1&CAR_ID=$2 [L]

# http://myserver.com/backend-api/user/$userid/<any>.do
RewriteRule ^backend-api/user/(\w{12})/(\w+)\.do$ $2.php?USER_ID=$1 [L]

# http://myserver.com/backend-api/car/$carid/<any>.do
RewriteRule ^backend-api/car/(\w{12})/(\w+)\.do$ $2.php?CAR_ID=$1 [L]
```

Note the use of `RewriteBase`. This allows the URL-path to be removed from the `RewriteRule` substitution.

If `/backend-api` exists as a physical directory then these rules could instead go in `/backend-api/.htaccess`. Then you could remove the `RewriteBase` directive and modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* by removing the `backend-api/` portion from near the start of the pattern.

**UPDATE#3 - a future reference**

> Apparently `.htaccess` **DOES** by default apply all the rules that the conditions of are met. However, some CGI/Fast-CGI installations ruin it, resulting in the kind of behaviour depicted in the first example.

There are certainly some server (mis)configurations that appear to affect certain aspects of .htaccess/mod_rewrite, however, not in the way suggested earlier in your question and I have never encountered this directly myself. And this should have nothing to do with CGI/Fast-CGI. (?)

> ...Apache applies the `RewriteRules` not in the order in which they are listed in `.htaccess`, ...

Not sure exactly what you mean by this, but `RewriteRules` **are** processed "in the order in which they are listed in `.htaccess`" - this is fundamental to how mod_rewrite works. (However, different *modules* execute at different times, regardless of the order in `.htaccess`, but within each module the directives execute top-down, in order. eg. mod_rewrite executes before mod_alias (usually), so if you have a mod_alias `Redirect` before a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`, the `RewriteRule` is still processed first - which is why it is a bad idea to mix redirects from both modules, as you can end up with confusing conflicts.)

> ...but it starts 'scanning' the URL from its beginning, and as soons as the conditions for ANY of the rules are met, the URL gets modified accordingly.

Exactly, in the order in which they appear in the file.

Note that it's the `RewriteRule` directives that are scanned (top - down), not the conditions (ie. `RewriteCond` directives) - in case that is what you were implying. If the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path then the preceding `RewriteCond` directives are processed and if all these pass then the substitution occurs. (Which is why it is always more efficient to match what you can with the `RewriteRule` and not rely totally on the `RewriteCond` directives - the `RewriteRule` is processed first, not the `RewriteCond` directives.)

Crucially, (and this might be where you are tripping up?), is that if you have multiple `RewriteRule` directives then the following `RewriteRule` directives match against the output/substitution of the previously matched `RewriteRule` (if any), not against the URL-path of the initial request. Only the first matched `RewriteRule` matches against the URL-path of the request. So, yes, `RewriteRule` directives do *chain* together.

The exception to this is the `L` (`LAST`) flag on the `RewriteRule`. This "breaks" the *chain*. Although not completely... it causes the current round of processing to stop, but then it all starts again from the top! Only when the URL passes through *unchanged* is processing finished. (However, in Apache 2.4 you do have the `END` flag - this does indeed halt processing completely.)

Comment: Thank you. Your code solves the problem presented, but does not really answer the question (and this is partly my fault, perhaps it is not phrased well enough). I would like to know if I can transform a URL with more than one RewriteRule. I can post an additional update if you are still interested in helping me out :)

Comment: Yes, please update your question with a "working" example. The problem with using "foo" and "nofoo" in your example (which I assume is not the real world strings), is that the code presented will result in an internal rewrite loop (500 error) since "foo" is contained in "nofoo". On the other hand, are you just dealing with whole-path-segments, rather than _anywhere_ in the URL?

Comment: Yes, I know, the original example was not a very good one:) Anyway, I hope I have improved my question a bit. Please take a look when you have a moment to spare!

Comment: I've updated my answer with respect to **UPDATE#2**.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and support. Your answer deserves to be accepted as the best one :) However, just suppose that for whatever reason **I HAVE TO** use two different RewriteRules on a single URL. Can this be achieved in .htaccess ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with respect to **UPDATE#3**. Yes, you can apply two different `RewriteRules` on a single URL - but note that the input of the 2nd is on the output of the 1st - I explain a bit more in my answer. (I'll try and address the first part of your question later.)